# Is it possible to capture TypeInitializationException when setting a value?

Tags: linq-to-sql, f#, type-providers

When using the SQL type provider when the app.config file does not supply a valid connection, a TypeInitializationException is thrown. I would like to capture this exception and return a more helpful message (such as "Your app.config file is missing"), but I'm having trouble. I've tried the following:

```
open System.Data
open System.Data.Linq
open Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders

type SqlConnection = Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.SqlDataConnection<ConnectionStringName = "DBConnectionString">

let DB1 =
    try  SqlConnection.GetDataContext()
    with | ex -> failwith "Exception 1"
```

When I try-catch this, the exception that I catch is actually a NullReferenceException, and my "Exception 1" then gets wrapped in a TypeInitializationException.

I can do this:

```
let getDB2 () =
    try DB1
    with | ex -> failwith "Exception 2"
```

...in which ex is the TypeInitializationException, and then it throws Exception 2 as I want, but when I try:

```
let DB3 =
    try getDB2()
    with | ex -> failwith "Exception 3"
```

...then it gets wrapped in another TypeInitializationException, which strangely has wrapped Exception 1 instead of Exception 3, seemingly bypassing the try-with block in DB3. (I should note that I'm calling all these things from C# when I'm doing my testing, in case that matters.)

Is it possible to avoid having the generic TypeInitializationException be the outer exception when trying to access the DB, without exposing it as a function? And why is the TypeInitializationException not caught like other exceptions?

**--- Addendum ---**

After fooling around a little more, I discovered that this behaviour occurs when setting ANY value. For example, this:

```
let x : int =
    try failwith "Exception A"
    with | ex -> failwith "Exception B"
```

...results in a TypeInitializationException wrapped around an Exception B.

Is this an F# thing, and is there any way to capture this exception during the setting of the value?

Comment: I'm sure you could intercept a type init exception with adding a handler to `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`, but Fyodors answer is far more satisfying.

Answer (score 2):

Your `DB1` is not a function, but a *value*. It gets evaluated when the module is loaded, which in .NET happens on the first attempt to access anything from the module. That's why your exception gets thrown as soon as you try to do *anything at all*.

Further, in .NET, any exception thrown during static initialization of a class (and F# modules are compiled as .NET classes) gets wrapped in a `TypeInitializationException` (I am not very clear on the rationale behind this).

If you want `DB1` to be a function, and to be evaluated only when called, give it a parameter. If you don't have any meaningful parameters to give, make it `unit` (denoted in F# by an empty pair of parentheses):

```
let DB1 () =
    try  SqlConnection.GetDataContext()
    with | ex -> failwith "Exception 1"
```

Comment: "F# modules are compiled as .NET classes" - this is the part I was missing. So the Type being initialized is the type of the module itself, and anything that happens when initializing a Type gets wrapped in a TypeInitializationException.

It is unfortunate, but it makes sense. I know it can be done by making it a function instead of a value, but I was hoping to avoid that as it slightly obfuscates the meaning of DB (to my thinking).

Thanks!

Comment: If you really meant to create a DB connection automatically at application start and have it always hang there as a global static value, I must say that's bad design.

Comment: I've been largely basing my experimentation on the examples at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361033.aspx, which doesn't provide much additional context.

Answer (score 0):

Your `DB1` is a disposable resource and as such, you really should not be creating during module initialization anyway, but rather either return it.

```
let createDB1 () = new SqlConnection.GetDataContext()
```

and dispose of it at another appropriate place. Or (my personal preference, as you are less likely to forget the dispose) wrap hide the `DB1` completely and rather just inject it into a function

```
let usingDB1 f = 
    use db = new SqlConnection.GetDataContext()
    f db

let myFunc db = // do something meaningful here

usingDB1 myFunc
```